# Div element set as block. Why?

Tags: css, layout, html, block

I sometimes see DIV set to `display:block` Is there any particular reason considering DIV is already a block box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could be over-riding another CSS attribute that said

```
.myClass {
  display: inline;
}
```

Or replacing `display:none;` to "un-hide" it (typically this is done on-the-fly by javascript).

Answer (score 4):

It may be to override another style that may be setting it to something else, but otherwise it's most likely a reminder to whoever wrote it. There's no real reason to include that rule.

Answer (score 2):

If you're overriding an existing style it makes sense.  Setting a div to block that has no styles coming in from elsewhere does not.

Comment: Missed that wave.  Will just have to paddle faster next time :-p